# How to create submenu that remains opaque on hover ONLY AFTER hover on menu but not otherwise?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

A demo of this problem is here: https://jsfiddle.net/cwxLpf7j/62/

I am currently working on a project, where I want a navbar which has a specific designed menu. This menu is such that there are several menu items and a SINGLE sub menu. When I hover over any menu item, this submenu (which is positioned absolutely) is moved beneath that menu item using JavaScript. I have completed the moving portion of the code.

However, there is a slight problem. I have used a transition on opacity of the submenu to hide (opacity:0) and show (opacity:1) it when required. So, I put event listeners on the menu items and it worked well. However, now the problem is that when I leave (mouseleave) the menu item and go into the submenu itself, the submenu disappears and I cannot do anything with the buttons/links in the submenu. Now, I cannot put event listeners on the sub menu itself, because it is present but transparent (which will trigger hover events when not wanted). I also tried to play around with "display: none" but that destroyed the beautiful transition on the opacity.

I hope you understood. I have created a small demo of what I did here: https://jsfiddle.net/cwxLpf7j/62/.

Here is the code anyways:

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll("li");
const box = document.querySelector(".box");

// This portion adds event listeners to each item in the list
// which hide or show (change opacity) of the box below.

listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    box.style.opacity = 1;
  })
  item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    box.style.opacity = 0;
  })
})

// If I add hover event on the box itself, it will trigger
// without actually having to hover over the list item. Also
// I tried playing with display:none to hide the box fully when
// the list is not being hovered. But that caused to destroy
// the transition on the opacity fully.
// UNCOMMENT THIS PORTION OF CODE TO SEE WHAT I DID

// box.addEventListener("mouseenter", ()=>{
//     box.style.opacity = 1;
// })
// box.addEventListener("mouseleave", ()=>{
//     box.style.opacity = 0;
// })
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 4px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<div class="box">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati impedit, ad. Accusamus tenetur vel praesentium quas vero, voluptates ipsam vitae officia, ut culpa dolor porro, officiis incidunt aspernatur nostrum facilis!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears – at first glance – to be possible with just CSS:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* to ensure that hovering the sub-menu doesn't trigger the
     sub-menu to reveal itself while hidden: */
  pointer-events: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 4px;
}

/* here use the :is() pseudo-class function, along with the
   adjacent-sibling combinator ('+') to style the .box element
   whenever the ul matches any of the pseudo-classes within
   that function; we also couple this selector with the .box
   class-selector to match those same states: */
ul:is(:hover, :active, :focus, :focus-within) + .box,
.box:is(:hover, :active, :focus, :focus-within) {
  /* we revert the pointer-events to auto, to enable
     interaction: */
  pointer-events: auto;
  /* and, of cousre, update the opacity as before: */
  opacity: 1;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<div class="box">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati impedit, ad. Accusamus tenetur vel praesentium quas vero, voluptates ipsam vitae officia, ut culpa dolor porro, officiis incidunt aspernatur nostrum facilis!</p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qwzj9Lpm/).

The caveat of the above approach is that the `.box` element's display and interactivity is based on an interaction with the `<ul>` rather than its descendant `<li>` elements, as there is (as yet) no parent-selector in CSS.

This approach, though, can be modified using JavaScript to apply, or remove, a class-name on – or other attribute-value of –  the parent `<ul>` as below:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(
  (elem) => {
    elem.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      elem.parentNode.classList.add('isInteractive');
    });
    elem.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      elem.parentNode.classList.remove('isInteractive');
    });
  });
```

```css
.box{
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 4px;
}

/* I added this rule purely to offer a visual demonstration of the
   class-name "isInteractive" being added and removed; it's in no
   way required for the demo to work: */
ul.isInteractive {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff0, lime);
}

/* modified the selector, below, to style the ".box" on interaction
   with the <ul> only once the "isInteractive" class is added to the
   <ul>: */
ul.isInteractive + .box,
.box:is(:hover, :active, :focus, :focus-within) {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<div class="box">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati impedit, ad. Accusamus tenetur vel praesentium quas vero, voluptates ipsam vitae officia, ut culpa dolor porro, officiis incidunt aspernatur nostrum facilis!</p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qwzj9Lpm/1/).

One warning with the above code, specifically to do with this selector rule-set:

```
ul:is(:hover, :active, :focus, :focus-within) + .box,
.box:is(:hover, :active, :focus, :focus-within) { ... }
```

If a browser doesn't understand any of the rules, then it will discard the whose set of rules; so it may be worth typing it out – for compatibility purposes – to the older format of:

```
ul:hover + .box,
ul:active + .box,
ul:focus + .box,
ul:focus-within + .box,
.box:hover,
.box:active,
.box:focus,
.box:focus-within { ... }
```

Because the above approach didn't seem to be particularly keyboard-accessible I've added some compensation that seems to better support keyboard-navigation, though this has led to me wrapping the `<li>` text in an `<a>` tag to enable tab-navigation. This updated approach is below:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(
  (elem) => {
    elem.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      elem.parentNode.classList.add('isInteractive');
    });
    elem.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      elem.parentNode.classList.remove('isInteractive');
    });
  });
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 4px;
}

ul:is(:hover, :active, :focus, :focus-within)+.box,
.box:is(:hover, :active, :focus, :focus-within) {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* this is to allow links to be less-visible within the <li>
   elements, if you don't want them to dominate your theme
   although it may be considered more accessible if you do
   allow your users to easily identify <a> elements: */
li a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}

/* here we style all <a> elements (modify to your aesthetic) to have
   default presentation in order to allow transitions: */
a {
  outline: solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

/* we transition to these styles in order to allow some movement
   to occur to draw the eye: */
a:is(:focus, :active, :hover) {
  outline: solid #0cc;
  outline-offset: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="box">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati impedit, ad. <a href="#">Accusamus tenetur</a> vel praesentium quas vero, voluptates ipsam vitae officia, ut culpa dolor porro, officiis incidunt aspernatur nostrum facilis!</p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qwzj9Lpm/2/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within).
  - [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is).
  - [`:outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).
  - [`:outline-offset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I could think of is to enclose menu and info box into a container and listen for events on that container.

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll("li");
const box = document.querySelector(".box");
const menu = document.querySelectorAll(".menu");
for(let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++)
{
  menu[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", onMouseEvent, true); //event listener on all children as well
  menu[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", onMouseEvent); //to make it simple we only listen on .menu box
}

function onMouseEvent(e)
{
  const isMouseEnter = e.type == "mouseenter";
  if (isMouseEnter && e.target.tagName != "LI")
    return;

  box.classList.toggle("show", isMouseEnter); //avoid using inline style
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box.show
{
  opacity: 1;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 4px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu
{
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati impedit, ad. Accusamus tenetur vel praesentium quas vero, voluptates ipsam vitae officia, ut culpa dolor porro, officiis incidunt aspernatur nostrum facilis!</p>
</div>
```